# What is the purpose of ContextType.Domain and from where its value is being set

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code inside my asp.net mvc web application :-

```
PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADServerName, "OU=ComanyNAMe,OU=Users", "username", "password"))
```

I know that the second parameter represents the AD server name , search,, and the username and password. But what is ContextType.Domain, and from where its value is being initiated ?
Thnaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an enumeration from `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace. It specifies the type of store to which the principal belongs, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.contexttype(v=vs.110).aspx)

To create a specific principal instance (`PrincipalContext`) you have to specify its first parameter that gives meaning to other params (name, container etc.). Without such discriminator the constructor would not know what refers to. As [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.contexttype(v=vs.110).aspx) states you can refer to:

- ApplicationDirectory - The application directory store. This represents the AD LDS store.
- Domain - The domain store. This represents the AD DS store.
- Machine - The computer store. This represents the SAM store.

You can look at an example of managing active directory using PrincipalContext [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b3029d8c-af8d-4fa1-b08f-f8650af376c8/manage-active-directory-with-c-directoryentry-or-principalcontext?forum=csharpgeneral). Or for more comprehensive explanation you can read [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321350170).

Comment: but I mean I didi not set its value, so from where it get its value?

Comment: I have edited the original answer to better explain this topic to you. Hope it helps now.